# how to combine two variables in cmd.exe script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a cmd.exe script on Windows 7, I want to combine two variables to set a third.

Eg. (which doesn't work)

```
SET THIRD=%FIRST%%SECOND%
```

How can I do this ?

---

Apologies to everyone who even looked at this question.  The example above works perfectly and I cannot reproduce the problem I was having.  Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: Your example works for me. What OS? I used WinXP.

Comment: Can you provide a sample along with its output and how it differs from what you want?  If you're trying to set a variable in a FOR loop, see my example here using `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209652/string-processing-using-batch-script/4210607#4210607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quotes?

```
SET "THIRD=%FIRST%%SECOND%"
```

Comment: Just to close this off, I have accepted your answer.  I cannot reproduce the problem I was seeing.  Thanks.